# Conflict in jQuery with Active Reports

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am using jQuery 1.10.2 in my project. At one page I need to show the reports with Active Report 9.

The problem is that it is loading jQuery 1.7.2. I tried to resolve the conflict using `var jq17= $.noConflict(true);` which changes the alias from `$` to `jq17`.

Now is it necessary to change the aliases in all .jq libraries loading with Active Report 9 to use jq17 as a new alias ? Or is there any other way to go ahead without changing the libraries.

**Update:** I have tried the answer from @Andreas. It solved the alias issue. But some functions of Active Report are not accessible through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the 1.7.2 version and call `.noConflict(true)` before loading the version 1.10.2 (or vice versa if it would be easier that way), wrap the 1.7.2 dependent code in an anonymous function and pass it the `noConflict` version to alias it as `$`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
    var jq172 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($) {
        console.log($.fn.jquery);  // -> 1.7.2
    }(jq172));

    console.log($.fn.jquery);  // -> 1.10.2
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
What if I have different dependant .js files and chunks of dependant code in different <script> tags.
and what to do if some libraries are using jQuery as Alias?

Comment: Anything that requires a special version would have to be wrapped in a block as shown in my answer.

Comment: It seems that it is working. 
but some functions of Active Reports are not accessible now.
e.g. ReferenceError: ViewerViewModel is not defined, 
TypeError: ArInitViewModels is not a function

Comment: Try the other way round. Load 1.10.2 first, `noConflict` it, load 1.7.2 as second and put all your code into the anonymous function, passing 1.10.2 into it, and the ActiveReports outside

Comment: Not a Possible solution for this.
Anyways thanks a lot for your answer.
It helped a lot though.